# Реализация ArrayStack и ArrayStackIterator, используя абстрактные классы

Tags: c++, классы, наследование

У меня вот такое вот задание:
используя абстрактные классы, реализовать конкретные классы: ArrayStack(на массиве) и ArrayStackIterator.

в header.cpp я поместил такие классы:

```
// абстрактный базовый класс Итератор
class AbstractIterator {
public:
    virtual ~AbstractIterator() {};
    virtual bool InRange() const = 0;       // индекс в допустимых пределах? 
    virtual void Reset() = 0;           // сбросить индекс в начало
    virtual int& operator *() const = 0;        // разыменование (чтение элемента)
    virtual void operator ++() = 0;         // сдвиг на элемент
};
// абстрактный базовый класс Контейнер
class AbstractContainer {
public:
    virtual ~AbstractContainer() {};
    virtual bool IsEmpty() const = 0;       // контейнер пуст
    virtual bool IsFull()  const = 0;       // контейнер полный
};
// абстрактный базовый класс Стек
class AbstractStack : public AbstractContainer {
public:
    virtual void push(const int& n) = 0;        // втолкнуть в стек
    virtual int pop(void) = 0;          // вытолкнуть из стека
};

// класс Стек на базе массива
class ArrayStack : public AbstractStack {
protected:
    int     size;   // размерность массива
    int* p;     // указатель на массив
    int     top;    // верхушка стека
public:
    ArrayStack(int _size);
    ArrayStack(ArrayStack& s);
    ~ArrayStack();
    void push(const int& n);        // втолкнуть в стек
    int pop(void);          // вытолкнуть из стека
    bool IsEmpty() const;
    bool IsFull() const;
    friend class ArrayStackIterator;
};
// класс Итератор стека
class StackIterator;
class ArrayStackIterator : public AbstractIterator {
    ArrayStack& a;          // ссылка на стек
    int     pos;            // текущая позиция итератора
    StackIterator();
public:
    ArrayStackIterator(const ArrayStack& _a);
    bool InRange() const;           // индекс в допустимых пределах
    void Reset();               // сбросить индекс в начало
    int& operator *() const;        // разыменование (чтение элемента)
    void operator ++();         // сдвиг на элемент
};
```

А как написать эту реализацию? Я очень туплю(
Как используя абстрактные классы описать методы класса ArrayStack и ArrayStackIterator?
может вопросы не правильно задаю

Comment: вообще несколько странно реализовывать итератор на базе абстрактного класса. Я бы даже сазал бессмысленно, так как с ним будет проблематично работать: нужно будет использовать умные указатели, либо вручную подчищать память, а в стандартных алгоритмах у вас его вообще не получится использовать. Может задание касалось только контейнера (в части абстрактного интерфейса), а не итератора?

Comment: Ну вот такое вот обучение в универе. Мне б просто хотя бы понять как это реализовать) Это просто нужно реализовать, работать с ним будут только я и преподовательница))

Comment: в том то и дело, что просто (с итератором) не получится - просто реализуется стандартным способом, через `type_traits`.

Comment: Ух, спасибо, сейчас попробую разобраться)